# How to download a file on a webpage that is not a direct link but a javascript click.submit()?

Tags: wget

Examples are http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/downloads/

The files are listed in a table that need javascript to run on `click.submit()`.
wget is not working in this case.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9809896/284605

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `wget  --post-data` to construct a string with all the values that were gonna be sent in the form, also `--content-disposition` and `--trust-server-names` to allow the use of server supplied names. You also need to use the page url itself, since the form action is `""`.

From the first form in the page:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="download-1">
  <input type="hidden" value="12a6c92ab9" name="amd_developer_central_nonce" id="amd_developer_central_nonce">
  <input type="hidden" value="/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/downloads/" name="_wp_http_referer">
  <input type="hidden" value="QU1ELUFQUC1TREstdjIuOS1sbngzMi50Z3o=" name="f">
</form>
```

You will construct the following command: `wget --content-disposition --trust-server-names --post-data='amd_developer_central_nonce=12a6c92ab9&_wp_http_referer=/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/downloads/&f=QU1ELUFQUC1TREstdjIuOS1sbngzMi50Z3o=' http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/downloads/`, in action:

```
aularon ~ $  wget --content-disposition --trust-server-names --post-data='amd_developer_central_nonce=12a6c92ab9&_wp_http_referer=/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/downloads/&f=QU1ELUFQUC1TREstdjIuOS1sbngzMi50Z3o=' http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/downloads/
--2014-02-04 23:39:49--  http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/downloads/
Resolving developer.amd.com (developer.amd.com)... 50.116.16.216
Connecting to developer.amd.com (developer.amd.com)|50.116.16.216|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 100284370 (96M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9-lnx32.tgz’

 4% [==>                                     ] 4,452,576    544KB/s  eta 3m 4s  ^C
```